# Any ideas as to what I might be picking up on SDR?

Tags: software-defined-radio, vhf, signal-identification

Any ideas as to what I might be picking up on SDR? They make for some strange patterns. Picked them up at the following coordinates: (31.514596, 74.345092) using GQRX, tuned to 217.25 MHz. As for the second snapshot, I'm not sure what the exact frequency was but it was close to 217.25 MHz.

[image: A strange pattern]

[image: Another one on a similar frequency]

Comment: Can you provide your location, your setup, frequency and time axes on your plots, and spectrogram parameters?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com! Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Comment: Do the side tones disappear quicker than the centre tone if you reduce gain? Might be clipping or intermodulation!

Comment: What's the relationship between the first and second pictures, if any?

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II no relationship

Comment: The first signal is almost certainly just noise from some electronics, possibly the receiver itself. Notice how it doesn't change over time: this means it contains no information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it might be European television broadcasting. What is your location?"

From the spectrum, it's neither video or DAB.

Looks like a spurious or other radiation from a nearby source.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

According to https://fccid.io/frequency-explorer.php?lower=217.2&upper= it might be European television broadcasting. What is your location?